# Which version(s) of Super Mario World are allowed when speedrunning on SpeedRunsLive?

Tags: super-mario-world, speedrun

I am interested in Speedrunning Super Mario World on SpeedRunsLive, but I was wondering if there are restrictions on what versions are allowed. In particular, are there restrictions on whether you use the Japanese/North American/European releases or whether you use the Snes or Wii version.

The [SpeedRunsLive](http://www.speedrunslive.com/races/game/#!/smw/1) page for the game only specifies that the GBA version is not allowed.

Finally, is Snes9x 1.53 allowed as an emulator?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how the rules work for a specific site.  We deal with games, not the sites that cover them.

Comment: @Frank I disagree. Speedrunning is totally within our expertise, and the rules related to it are pretty standard (any official version is 100% okay, emulators must be slower than the fastest official version).

Comment: @Unionhawk Speedrunning, yes.  Interpreting rules of a site that does speedruns, no.

Comment: @Frank And anyone who is a speedrunner or is familiar with speedrunning will be familiar with SRL. This is 100% within our expertise.

Comment: I think if Speedrunning is on-topic then the rules for one of the major speedrunning websites should be. A big part of speedrunning is competition, which relies on following a common set of rules.

Comment: A website is **not** within our expertise.  We are gamers, and cannot be expected to be familiar with a specific website's rules or processes.  It doesn't matter what website that is, unless it's Arqade itself.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's on topic, an answer from that web site itself would be a lot more authoritative than an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any official version of Super Mario World (except, in this case the GBA version). As far as emulators go, you can find a list of banned emulators [here](http://www.speedrunslive.com/faq/rules/). According to that list, Snes9x 1.53 *should* be allowed, but I would ask SRL moderation just to be safe. You should be good to use it though.

Keep in mind, though, that if you do play on emulator, you *have* to livestream the whole thing, and ensure that the VOD is available after you are done streaming. You may be disqualified otherwise. In any case, you should have some ability to proof anyway, and livestreaming and recording the thing is the best way to do that.

Comment: Keep in mind, also, that any allowed emulator will perform a little more slowly than a console. So your best bet will always be playing on console.

Comment: Unionhawk seems to know a lot. Even when its for a website question that was asked on a Video Game question site. Still, good job on knowing this stuff.